# RegEx for matching and extracting UL & DL speeds into variables

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to monitor file transfers. Output is:

```
Status: Uploading UL: 0.0 KiB/s

Status: Paused

Status: Downloading DL: 358.9 KiB/s ETA: 1h 27m

Status: Stopped

Status: Uploading UL: 25.8 MiB/s ETA: 25m 30s
```

I'd like to use a perl regex to pull these into `$dl_speed`, `$ul_speed` and `$eta`.

Can you send me on the right way?

Comment: Being a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it helps others and in turn they can help you back, else your post may be downvoted (although I didn't downvote your post) and closed.

Comment: You are expected to show your attempt at solving this, please show the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be the correct direction. However, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/hMe9yz/1) might help you to match your UL and DL variables.

```
(UL:\s|DL:\s)([0-9\.]+)(\sKiB\/s|\sMiB\/s)
```

It has three capturing groups:

- The right one is where your units go, and you can simply add more with an <kbd>|</kbd>.
- The left boundary is similar to the right one.
- In the middle group, only numbers and <kbd>.</kbd> is allowed, without spaces.

You can also reduce boundaries and much simplify this RegEx, if you wish.

You may make sure, if there are other Perl-required checks to follow through.

[image]

In case, you had more spaces in between your float numbers and the units, you might work on this [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/a5OKiX/1):

```
(UL:\s+|DL:|\s+)([0-9\.]+)(\s+KiB\/s|\s+MiB\/s)
```

[image]

If you wish to get the three variables, you might add one matching set for `UL` and `DL`, and another set for `ETA`, maybe similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/tmTKWw/1)

```
((UL:\s+|DL:\s+)([0-9\.]+)(\s+KiB\/s|\s+MiB\/s))|((ETA:\s+)([0-9hms]+\s[0-9hms]+))
```

I have added several boundaries, since I'm not really sure, how your possible inputs may look like. You can much simplify, if you wish so.

[image]